# Joing MYSQL row results (e.g Article info) with Multilple sub rows (e.g Comments) to one var in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, symfony1

Tried searching, not sure if using right words.

Ok so I want to pass every announcements paired with each announcements multiple comments to a template in 1 variable (so I dont have to put business logic there). Any ideas how to do this?

Heres what I have so far: http://pastebin.com/JvKXtB5a

Getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error, you're making an array as an index to an array, you can't do that. What you're doing in something like:

```
$annoucementarray = array('value'); // assuming this is the value
$tmparray = array($annoucementarray => 'test'); // Warning: Illegal offset
```

You cannot use an array as an index, in your case you want `$annoucementarray` to be the index of a new array assigned to `$tmparray`.